# C# Excel PivotItem Visibility

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I want to use C# to get the values of the checkboxes from the Excel Filter.
[image]

so ...

```
Proj_1 should be true
Proj_2 should be true
Proj_3 should be false
Proj_4 should be false
```

Below is the code I am currently using but item.Visible is ALWAYS false no matter if the UI has a check by it or not (unless I uncheck Select Multiple Items) but I need that checked

```
  foreach (PivotField fld in pivotFields)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fld.Name + " -- " + fld.Orientation + " -- " + fld.EnableItemSelection + " -- " + fld.EnableMultiplePageItems + " -- ");

                    foreach (PivotItem item in fld.PivotItems(Type.Missing))
                    {
                        if (item.Visible == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Item"  + item.Name + " in field " + fld.Name + "is Visible  (Selected)");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Item" + item.Name + " in field " + fld.Name + "is Hidden (Not Selected)");
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Writing a [MCVE] is really the first step to getting an answer in StackOverflow. The way you have written the question, there are not more than 100 people, who could answer (and 95 probably work as Excel engineers at Microsoft). If you have added the whole code, the number of people jumps to 100^3.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that works, if the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library is added:

[image]

```
namespace ExcelAtSomething
{
    using System;
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    class Startup
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\stackoverflow\Desktop\Sample.xlsx";
            Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            excel.EnableAnimations = true;

            Excel.Workbook wkb = Open(excel, filePath);

            foreach (Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet in wkb.Worksheets)
            {
                Excel.PivotTables pivotTablesCollection = xlWorksheet.PivotTables();
                if (pivotTablesCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pivotTablesCollection.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Excel.PivotTable currentPivotTable = pivotTablesCollection.Item(i);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Table is named -> {currentPivotTable.Name}");

                        foreach (Excel.PivotField pivotField in currentPivotTable.PivotFields())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"\nField is named -> {pivotField.Name}");
                            foreach (Excel.PivotItem visibleItems in pivotField.VisibleItems)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Visible item name -> {visibleItems.Name}");
                            }

                            foreach (Excel.PivotItem PivotItem in pivotField.PivotItems())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Item is named -> {PivotItem.Name}");
                                Console.WriteLine(PivotItem.Visible);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            excel.EnableAnimations = true;
            wkb.Close(true);
            excel.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        }

        private static Excel.Workbook Open(Excel.Application excelInstance,
                string fileName, bool readOnly = false,
                bool editable = true, bool updateLinks = true)
        {
            Excel.Workbook book = excelInstance.Workbooks.Open(
                fileName, updateLinks, readOnly,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, editable, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            return book;
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is that except for `PivotItem`, there is a PivotField, which has a list of its visible items. If you display these, then only the visible ones are displayed:

[image]

Playing a bit and probably making custom a function, that returns the non-visible items, which are not in that list is a good option for the Excel.

Comment: Yeah I actually want to know what values are checked ....Like in my example Proj_1 /.. True Proj_2 ... true I don't care about the actual data in the pivot.

Comment: Why can't i see the `.PivotFields()` collection? I am using the latest version of `Interop`

Comment: FYI if it helps anyone, this is how I had to access a pivotfield:  `currentPivotTable = pivotTablesCollection.Item("ptName");
                vf = (Excel.PivotFields)currentPivotTable.VisibleFields;
                foreach (Excel.PivotField f in vf)
                {
                    if (f.Name == "fieldName")
                        f.BaseItem = "20200101";
                } `